# Chotchkies Restaurant

Tags: math, fastest-code

Because there isn't enough xkcd on PPCG...

[image]

### Challenge

The challenge is the same as above - given a menu and a total price, you need to find what the customer ordered.

The menu will be supplied as a text file in the format:

```
Name:Price
Name:Price
```

The path to the menu file and the total price should be supplied via argv or STDIN.
If you wish, the menu may be supplied via STDIN/argv (instead of newlines, separate each item by commas).

The output should be a list of values. If there are multiple answers, output all of them.

## Example

Menu:

```
Burger:12.60
Pepsi:3.50
Lobster Thermidore:33.10
Ice Cream:23.00
```

Total Price: `68.70`

The output is:

```
Burger
Lobster Thermidore
Ice Cream
```

### Winning

The fastest code given an undisclosed problem wins. The speed will be taken five times and averaged.

Comment: Can the menu be directly input via STDIN/arguments ?

Comment: Limitation of a file makes a lot of programming languages impossible to use here.

Comment: What do you mean by fastest code ? Time wise ? Complexity wise ? If its time wise, then its completely unfair

Comment: Why unfair? I assume OP will run the undisclosed test case on their machine. However, it should be run multiple times for each submission to rule out noise. It also begs the question if there are limitations of the languages that can be used.

Comment: @IngoBürk If there are two answers, 1 in JS and 1 in C, JS one is bound to be slower what so ever.

Comment: (Given they use similar algorithms)

Comment: @Optimizer Won't that be the case in every fastest code challenge though?

Comment: Generally fastest code challenges have some common platform to test things out and the test cases are big enough to diminish the gaps enough.

Comment: @Optimizer I will try and make sure that the problem is big enough (100 items on the menu, say?) then.

Comment: I agree with the comments on speed both here and in the answer. You're going to need a huge menu, and even with 100 items parsing the menu might take longer than running the algorithm (depending on your disk and api.) I do think this would have (still would?) make an excellent codegolf.

Comment: @steveverrill Edited to make it code golf

Comment: @steveverrill: I guess you got me wrong. 100 items would take forever, since 2^100 is a huge number of possible combinations to test. I was trying to say that 2^50 is *already* huge, thus both approaches mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Exponential_time_algorithm) might be intractable.

Comment: @Falko perhaps my statement was a little hasty. But to really need to search 2^100 possibilities, there would have to be 2^100 distinct totals, which means bills up to 2^100 cents. With a realistic bill value in the range 0 to 2^16 cents ($0 to $655.36) there would have to be multiple ways of reaching many of the totals, so you might get a lucky hit fairly quickly.

Comment: @steveverrill: Yeah, ok. You're have something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) in mind. But the OP says: "If there are multiple answers, output all of them." ;)

Comment: @Falko Oops, I missed that bit about outputting all of them! That could be a lot of text...

Comment: See Peter Taylor's comment above - code golf makes this a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python 2 - Naive implementation - 224

Well, let's start with ["the most naive algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Exponential_time_algorithm) as some kind of reference solution:

```
import itertools

path = input()
total = input()

with open(path) as f:
    menu = map(lambda l: l.split(':'), f.read().split('\n'))

names, prices = zip(*menu)
prices = map(float, prices)

for i in range(len(menu)):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(range(len(menu)), i):
        if sum(prices[c] for c in comb) == total:
            for i in comb:
                print names[i]
```

**Input:**

```
"data.txt"
68.70
```

**Output:**

```
Burger
Lobster Thermidore
Ice Cream
```

**Complexity:**

```
O(2^N * N)
```

--> exponential in the number of menu items `N` (of course)

---

**Edit:**

To reflect the new winning criterion I golfed it down quite a bit:

```
from itertools import*
S=str.split
f,t=S(input())
m=[S(l,':')for l in S(open(f).read(),'\n')]
R=range(len(m))
F=float
for i in R:
 for C in combinations(R,i):
  if sum(F(m[c][1])for c in C)==F(t):
   for j in C:print m[j][0]
```

The input format changed to `data.txt 68.70` (both on one line separated with a whitespace).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the naive implementation is the only one anyone is going to have the stamina for.

Comment: @COTO: Agree. And if tested with a menu filled with 100 appetizers (!?) a complexity of O(2^N * N) vs. O(2^(N/2)) doesn't even matter. ;)

Comment: Sorry for being so indecisive, but to avoid this being marked as a dupe, I've changed it back to fastest code.